# Which word should I use?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I'm having a hard time choosing which word to choose, was or were.

For example,

**Were**

> They were feeling joyful ever since she came back.

**Was**

> Chris and his friends was feeling joyful ever since Jennifer came back.

Another example,

**Were**

> I pity the animals sent to space for their sacrifice were needed whether human astronauts could survive in space.

**Was**

> I pity Laika and all the other mentionable animals for their sacrifice
> was needed whether human astronauts could survive in space.

*Do subjects and proper nouns have anything to do with choosing which words to use? Please explain the difference between the two words.*

Comment: "Their sacrifice was needed _to test_ whether human astronauts could survive..."

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that word just after randomhead posted his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Was" and "were" are the past tense forms of the irregular verb **to be**:

| Person | Singular | Plural |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | I was | we were |
| Second | you were | you (all) were |
| Third | he/she/it was | they were |

In your first example the subject is "They" or "Chris and his friends." Look at the table: *were* is correct and *was* is incorrect.

In your second example the relevant subject is "sacrifice." Look at the table: *were* is incorrect and *was* is correct.

Note however that there are multiple errors in your second example sentence, and if they were corrected than the verb would actually be "were."